# How to change month in FSCalendar?

Tags: ios, swift, fscalendar

I am working with FSCalendar and I want to customize it according to my requirement. So, I have a list of months in a view controller and the same controller has FSCalendar. What I want is that when I click on any particular month the calender changes to that month only.

The list of months is in a collectionview. On clicking the cell I am showing the previous month but I don't how to show any particular month.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let currentCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? AttendenceMonthCell {
          // what code should I write here to get the particular month     
            let month = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .month, value: -1, to: calender.currentPage)
            calender.setCurrentPage(month!, animated: true)
        }
    }
```

I have googled alot but haven't got any answers yet. Is this possible with FSCalendar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, find the current month and subtract from the selected cell index. Like this.

```
let index = indexPath.item + 1
let currentMonth = Calendar.current.component(.month, from: Date())

let month = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .month, value: index - currentMonth, to: calender.currentPage)
calender.setCurrentPage(month!, animated: true)
```

Comment: I would like to ask you one more question. How can we get a particular month of a particular year?

Comment: Please asked in new question with full details and related codes.

Answer (score 0):

I change month by using buttons for next & previous month. I think this may useful for you.

next

```
let currentPage = self.fsCalendarView.currentPage
self.fsCalendarView.setCurrentPage(currentPage.addingComponentsOfDate(year: 0, month: 1, day: 0)!, animated: true)
```

prev

```
let currentPage = self.fsCalendarView.currentPage
self.fsCalendarView.setCurrentPage(currentPage.addingComponentsOfDate(year: 0, month: -1, day: 0)!, animated: true)
```